# Cannot get node or ts-node/register to use es2020 anymore (flatMap is not a function)

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, tsconfig

I am unable to use flatmap with node or ts-node despite previously being able to in my code. I am not sure what changed but I am getting this error `'TypeError: [x].flatMap is not a function'` flatMap() should be a function because I explicitly make x an array (this code was working before no problems).

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "target": "es2020",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "outDir": "out",
      //"strictBindCallApply": true,
      //"strict": true
    }
}
```

and here is my lancher

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
            "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "esm"],
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Tests",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "-u",
                "tdd",
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "--require",
                "esm",
                "--require",
                "ts-node/register",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/tsconfig.json",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*spec.ts"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

and the flatmap call in question

```js
(x: discord.Message | discord.Message[] | null): (discord.Message | null)[] => [x].flatMap(
                                // @ts-ignore
                                (t: discord.Message | discord.Message[] | null): (discord.Message | discord.Message[] | null) => t
                            )
```

another example that does not work:

```js
const test = [1,3,4,[5,4,2]].flatMap(x => x);
```

`TypeError: [1,3,4,[5,4,2]].flatMap is not a function`

Neither ts-node/register or ts-node seems to respect `"target": "es2020"` anymore and I am not sure what exactly changed. VScode does have context for intellesense for flatMap. Can anyone explain to me why it is not working anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had a conflict in the version number of node after an install of a program. I have stopped using the snap package of node and started using nvm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I combed through many forums. Could not fix. The below fixed for me. This is one more thing that you can try.

My node version was 14.19.
I remember the same code working sometime back. So I tried to run it on version 12.
I had nvm installed before. I switched my node version to 12 using command nvm use 12. Surprisingly no error with this version.

So I tried updating my node version by running nvm install 14 which updated my version from 14.19 to 14.21. Now when I test, it worked fine.

NVM is a very useful tool when such issues occur. Remember to keep the version match

Thanks
Narayanan